# ¿Cómo crear un módulo que cambie dos valores en un vector? Pascal

Tags: array, pascal

Me gustaría saber como cambiar el valor de una variable por otra alojada en el mismo vector.

Ej:

Vector

```
pos1:4
pos2:5
pos3:6  
pos4:7  
pos5:8  
pos6:9  
pos7:10  
pos8:11  
pos9:12  
pos10:13
```

Cambio el 5 por ejemplo con el 9 entonces:

```
pos1:4  
pos2:9  
pos3:6  
pos4:7  
pos5:8  
pos6:5  
pos7:10  
pos8:11  
pos9:12  
pos10:13
```

El proceso lo escribí así.

```
procedure intercambio(var numero:vnum);
var
  i,pos,pos2,x,y,c: integer;
begin
  writeln('Ingrese dos valores.');
  readln(x);
  readln(y);
  for i:=1 to 10 do
  begin
   if x = numero[i] then
      pos:=i;
   if y = numero[i] then
    begin
     pos2:=i;
     numero[pos2]:=numero[pos];
     numero[pos]:=numero[i];
    end;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: Tenia mucho de no ver Pascal, no hay forma de que sepas cual numero te va a aparecer primero, por eso no puedes hacer el intercambio dentro del for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo asi:

```
procedure intercambio(var numero:vnum);
var
  i,pos,pos2,x,y,c: integer;
begin
  writeln('Ingrese dos valores.');
  readln(x);
  readln(y);
  for i:=1 to 10 do
  begin
   if x = numero[i] then
      pos:=i;
   if y = numero[i] then
      pos2:=i;               
   end;
   c=numero[pos2];
   numero[pos2]:=numero[pos];
   numero[pos]:=c;
end;
```